# How big is the performance loss in running a Debian server via VM Workstation under Windows Server 2003

Tags: performance, virtual-machines, vmware-workstation

I have been using VM Workstation for a while, hobby projects mostly. However, now I'd like to build a drupal-based image DB system, and this legacy Win2003 is the only server available. There are already several applications running on it and virtual machine seems to be the only solution.

Last time I checked, there is an about 10% performance loss while running my programs in VM Workstation. And those are only small programs while my future server is suppose to be dealing with 2TB of high resolution photos. It is a internal DB so concurrent requests should not be a big problem, but I am not so confident about the I/O performance.

Do anyone has any similar experience on this?

Comment: Find another piece of hardware and use a Type 1 hypervisor. Done.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can you help me with my capacity planning?](http://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VMware Workstation you can add a physical drive to a VM with direct/exclussive access to it.
That way you will avoid any I/O issues on your VM.

This will also reduce any overhead.
With a physical disk connected to your VM you will write directly to it to whatever filesystem your guest OS will use (so you will also be able to boot to the OS without virtualization in the future if needed).

You may also want to use VMware WSX to be able to remotely manage and automatically boot the VM on each reboot of the physical server.